# Javascript else if statement error

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have to make a javacript code that satisfy the triangle inequality theorem, which the two smaller sides adds up to be bigger than the largest side. I have to use javascript and use a prompt for users to enter three numbers. I can not ask the user to enter the largest number i have to find it by code. So below is what i got so far, but i keep getting an error at the first else if statement and so i wont run. Any idea whats wrong with my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        <!--


            var a = prompt("Enter the first side", "0");
                a = Number(a);
            var b = prompt("Enter the second side", "0");
                b = Number(b);
            var c = prompt("Enter the third side", "0");
                c = Number(c);

            if(a>=b, a>=c){
                if (b+c>a) {
                document.write("These numbers " + a + ", " + b + ", and " + c + " do satisfy the triangle inequality.1" );
                }
                else {
                document.write("These numbers " + a + ", " + b + ", and " + c + " do not satisfy the triangle inequality.1" );
                }
            else if(b>=c, b>=a) {
                if (c+a>b) {
                document.write("These numbers " + a + ", " + b + ", and " + c + " do satisfy the triangle inequality.2" );
                }
                else {
                document.write("These numbers " + a + ", " + b + ", and " + c + " do not satisfy the triangle inequality.2" );
                }
            }
            else {
                if (a+b>c) {
                document.write("These numbers " + a + ", " + b + ", and " + c + " do satisfy the triangle inequality.3" );
                }
                else {
                document.write("These numbers " + a + ", " + b + ", and " + c + " do not satisfy the triangle inequality.3" );
                }
            }
            }




        // -->
    </script>
```

Comment: You can't have a comma in an `if` statement, its `&&` for AND, and `||` for OR

Comment: You've made up javascript syntax, maybe Google for javascript syntax, or compound conditionals, etc.

Comment: you can use switch instead if, and change ','with && or ||

Comment: @DaveNewton I also find suggesting specific resources (nothing to in-depth on my part) is often helpful. I would suggest [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). Also, Zack, consider whether or not you need to attempt to cast the input as a number (whether or not that actually provides the validation that you need)

Comment: @Thomas I find that a search engine query string is enough. Also,  W3 Schools? No.

Comment: @DaveNewton I respect the opinion about W3 Schools (I hold it, too). It's gotten pretty (has always been ?) pretty garbage-y. I removed it from the comment.

Comment: Using prompts and document.write is really not a good starting place either for working with javascript and html in 2015. Neither is commonly used in the real world

Comment: @adeneo I mean, you *can* use a comma in an if statement, I just don't think that's what the OP wants to use. For example: `if (4, true) alert("hi");` This is because the comma operator returns the last thing in the "list."

Answer (score 2):

`if` statements test a single condition, not multiple ones.  Assuming you want to know that both `a` is greater than or equal to `b` AND `a` is greater than or equal to `c`, you need to use the [`&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_.28&&.29) operator:

```
if(a>=b && a>=c)
```

If it's an OR, it's the [`||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_(.7C.7C)) operator:

```
if(a>=b || a>=c)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing

```
if(a>=b, a>=c){
```

If you want to check both for true, use:

```
if (a >= b && a >= c)
```

If you want to check either or:

```
if (a > = || a >= c)
```

But in general, this code looks really bad.

Answer (score 0):

`if ((a >= b) && (a >= c))`

Search Google for "javascript if" or something like that to learn more.

I've also noticed that your problem is *very* different from your answer. You say you have to ask for two sides and compute the third, but in your answer you ask for all three and just inform the user if they got the values right...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use an if statement.

```
var input2 = [10, 30, 50, 150];
input2.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
console.log(input2[0]);
```

You can run this in firebug console of firefox to see what it does.  Corrected my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys I know my code is sloppy, but I am just starting out so in time I will get better. Here is the way i fixed the code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--

            var a = prompt("Enter the first side", "0");
                a = Number(a);
            var b = prompt("Enter the second side", "0");
                b = Number(b);
            var c = prompt("Enter the third side", "0");
                c = Number(c);

            if(a>=b && a>=c && b+c>a){ 
                document.write("These numbers " + a + ", " + b + ", and " + c + " do satisfy the triangle inequality." );
            } else if(b>=c && b>=a && c+a>b) {
                document.write("These numbers " + a + ", " + b + ", and " + c + " do satisfy the triangle inequality." );
            } else if(c>=a && c>=b && a+b>c) {
                document.write("These numbers " + a + ", " + b + ", and " + c + " do satisfy the triangle inequality." );
            } else {
                document.write("These numbers " + a + ", " + b + ", and " + c + " do not satisfy the triangle inequality." );
            }

        // -->
    </script>
```